Can a Lambert conformal conic projection be constructed geometrically?
A gnomonic projection can be constructed geometrically by putting a light source in the middle of a semi-transparent globe to project an image of half of tyat globe onto a plane. A stereographic projection can be created by instead putting the light source on the point of the surface of the globe that is the farthest away from the plane.
Is it possible to create a Lambert conformal conic projection in a similar fashion?
(I was also in belief that the Mercator projection could be constructed by putting the light source in the middle of the globe and putting a cylinder around it with a central axis that is the same as the rotation axis of the globe, but I now see that the projection you get if you do that does not become conformal.)
